# Find the equation of the parabola for which the line $m^2(y-10)-mx-1=0$ is a tangent for all real values of $m$

Tags: conic-sections

I have the solution with me, but it looks wrong. Please help me out

The given line is 
$$x=m(y-10)-\frac 1m$$

Comparing it with 
$$x-h=m(y-k)+\frac am$$

So $$h=0, ~ k=, ~ a=-1$$

Hence the equation is 
$$x^2=-4(y-10)$$

But the equation of tangent generally used is 
$y=mx +\frac am $, which only applies to $y^2=4ax$. How can we use it here?

Comment: This is an [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)). In maxima CAS: `solve([m^2*(y-10)-m*x-1, diff(m^2*(y-10)-m*x-1,m)],[x,y]);`
`[[x = -2/m,y = (10*m^2-1)/m^2]]` which is your parabola $y=10-x^2/4$.

Comment: Your solution is fine, here the parabola is of type $x^2=4ay$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think it’s wrong? If you reflect a $Y^2=4aX$ type parabola so that it’s an $X^2=4aY$ type instead, the generic equation of a tangent to it undergoes the same reflection. Your approach to the problem was fine.

Your solution is easily verified: From the equation of the tangents we have $y-10=\frac1m(m x+1)$. Substituting this into your parabola equation, $x^2+\frac4{m^2}(mx+1)=0$. The discriminant of this quadratic equation vanishes, just as required for the line to be a tangent.